# Extract set of Pages as separate files

Tags: pdf

I've a PDF file of 192 pages, what I want is to extract and save PDF file after every 8th page.

Means, Page 1 to Page 8 it should save in separate file and from 9 to 16 and so on.

every file should have 8 pages each. so 192/8=24 files. each saved file should be of 8 pages.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this requires third party tool. Have you tried searching on google like "PDF Split"?

Comment: New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Any update on this and whether or not you found use of my answer below of any help?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Sejda.com to split the PDF at every 8 pages](https://www.sejda.com/split-pdf).

[image: Split PDF by pages]

Upload your file and then type 8 in the "Split at every X pages" input. Click "Split" and then download the result when task completes.

Free service for documents up to 200 pages or 50Mb.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to do this and from its command line interface (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe`) the below syntax would complete what you need.

I can confirm that this works since this is the method I used for this type of a task personally at home.

**CLI Examples**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" C:\Path\origfilename.pdf cat 1-8 output C:\PathOut\newfilename1-8.pdf
```

---

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" C:\Path\origfilename.pdf cat 9-16 output C:\PathOut\newfilename9-16.pdf
```

---

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" C:\Path\origfilename.pdf cat 17-24 output C:\PathOut\newfilename17-24.pdf
```

---

**Batch Script Loop Example**

*Here's a way to put it all in a loop, set the sourcedir and outputdir, set the page numbers, etc. with this free tool. Adjust the variables accordingly for your needs.*

```
@ECHO ON
SET PDFtk="C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
SET sourcedir=C:\sourcepath
SET outputdir=C:\outputpath

FOR %%A IN (1-8, 9-16, 17-24, 25-32, 33-40, 
            41-48, 48-56, 57-64, 65-72, 73-80, 
            81-88, 89-96, 97-104, 105-112, 113-120, 
            121-128, 129-136, 137-144, 145-152, 153-160, 
            161-168, 169-176, 177-184, 185-192
) 

DO %PDFtk% %sourcedir%\origfilename.pdf cat %%A output %outputdir%\newfilename%%A.pdf
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**pdftk man page**](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/)
- `pdftk --help`

> ```
>   cat [<page ranges>]
>          Assembles (catenates) pages from input PDFs to create a new
>          PDF. Use cat to merge PDF pages or to split PDF pages from
>          documents. You can also use it to rotate PDF pages. Page
>          order in the new PDF is specified by the order of the given
>          page ranges. Page ranges are described like this:
>
>          <input PDF handle>[<begin page number>[-<end page num-
>          ber>[<qualifier>]]][<page rotation>]
>
>          Where the handle identifies one of the input PDF files, and
>          the beginning and ending page numbers are one-based refer-
>          ences to pages in the PDF file.  The qualifier can be even or
>          odd, and the page rotation can be north, south, east, west,
>          left, right, or down.
>
>          If a PDF handle is given but no pages are specified, then the
>          entire PDF is used. If no pages are specified for any of the
>          input PDFs, then the input PDFs' bookmarks are also merged
>          and included in the output.
>
>          If the handle is omitted from the page range, then the pages
>          are taken from the first input PDF.
>
>          The even qualifier causes pdftk to use only the even-numbered
>          PDF pages, so 1-6even yields pages 2, 4 and 6 in that order.
>          6-1even yields pages 6, 4 and 2 in that order.
>
>          The odd qualifier works similarly to the even.
>
>          The page rotation setting can cause pdftk to rotate pages and
>          documents.  Each option sets the page rotation as follows (in
>          degrees): north: 0, east: 90, south: 180, west: 270, left:
>          -90, right: +90, down: +180. left, right, and down make rela-
>          tive adjustments to a page's rotation.
>
>          If no arguments are passed to cat, then pdftk combines all
>          input PDFs in the order they were given to create the output.
>
>          NOTES:
>          * <end page number> may be less than <begin page number>.
>          * The keyword end may be used to reference the final page of
>          a document instead of a page number.
>          * Reference a single page by omitting the ending page number.
>          * The handle may be used alone to represent the entire PDF
>          document, e.g., B1-end is the same as B.
>          * You can reference page numbers in reverse order by prefix-
>          ing them with the letter r. For example, page r1 is the last
>          page of the document, r2 is the next-to-last page of the doc-
>          ument, and rend is the first page of the document. You can
>          use this prefix in ranges, too, for example r3-r1 is the last
>          three pages of a PDF.
>
>          Page Range Examples without Handles:
>          1-endeast - rotate entire document 90 degrees
>          5 11 20 - take single pages from input PDF
>          5-25oddwest - take odd pages in range, rotate 90 degrees
>          6-1 - reverse pages in range from input PDF
>
>          Page Range Examples Using Handles:
>          Say A=in1.pdf B=in2.pdf, then:
>          A1-21 - take range from in1.pdf
>          Bend-1odd - take all odd pages from in2.pdf in reverse order
>          A72 - take a single page from in1.pdf
>          A1-21 Beven A72 - assemble pages from both in1.pdf and
>          in2.pdf
>          Awest - rotate entire in1.pdf document 90 degrees
>          B - use all of in2.pdf
>          A2-30evenleft - take the even pages from the range, remove 90
>          degrees from each page's rotation
>          A A - catenate in1.pdf with in1.pdf
>          Aevenwest Aoddeast - apply rotations to even pages, odd pages
>          from in1.pdf
>          Awest Bwest Bdown - catenate rotated documents
>
>   shuffle [<page ranges>]
>          Collates pages from input PDFs to create a new PDF.  Works
>          like the cat operation except that it takes one page at a
>          time from each page range to assemble the output PDF.  If one
>          range runs out of pages, it continues with the remaining
>          ranges.  Ranges can use all of the features described above
>          for cat, like reverse page ranges, multiple ranges from a
>          single PDF, and page rotation.  This feature was designed to
>          help collate PDF pages after scanning paper documents.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Found this, give a try:

**How to split a PDF file**
https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/split-pdf-document.html

Comment: link only answers are discouraged here as links can break at any time. Please quote relevant parts in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDFsam, it's free and open source. Here is a simple tutorial on [how to split PDF files](http://www.pdfsam.org/pdf-split/) with PDFsam.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged here as links can break at any time. Please quote relevant parts in your answer.